# Array functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I am using jQuery in my web application. I want to use arrays, but I am not able to find out functions for arrays (add, remove or append elements in array) in jQuery. Is there any link related to jQuery array functions which will explain the jQuery array functions?

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that jQuery objects are NOT themselves arrays. They act like arrays in many ways -- they are indexed using the `eq()` method and have a `.length` property -- but most of the standard JavaScript array methods will not work on jQuery objects.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Have a look at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array
for documentation on JavaScript Arrays.
jQuery is a library which adds some magic to JavaScript which is a capable and featurefull scripting language.  The libraries just fill in the gaps - get to know the core!

Answer (score 24):

jQuery has very limited array functions since JavaScript has most of them itself. But here are the ones they have: *[Utilities - jQuery API](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities)*.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to get the max and min value in an array is as follows.
This has been explained at [get max & min values in array](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)

```
var myarray = [5,8,2,4,11,7,3];
// Function to get the Max value in Array
Array.max = function( array ){
return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

// Function to get the Min value in Array
Array.min = function( array ){
return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};
// Usage 
alert(Array.max(myarray));
alert(Array.min(myarray));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual jQuery](http://visualjquery.com/) site has some great examples of jQuery's array functionality. (Click "Utilities" on the left-hand tab, and then "Array and Object operations".)

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for jQuery called 'rich array' discussed in *[Rich Array jQuery plugin](http://vladimir-k.blogspot.com/2008/12/rich-array-jquery-plugin.html)* .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#first). It really makes things simple.

For example, removing elements from an array, you need to do:

```
_.without([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

And the result will be [1, 3].

It reduces the code that you write using [jQuery.grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), etc. in jQuery.

Comment: Why doesn't this library extend the Array object?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the jQuery functions [`.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) and [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a jQuery plugin that adds some methods on an array:

*[Implementing Prototype’s Array Methods in jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/implementing-prototypes-array-methods-in-jquery)*

This plugin implements [Prototype's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) library array methods such as:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$.protify(arr, true);
arr.all();  // true

var arr = $.protify([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
arr.any(); // true
```

And more.