# Writing Multidemisional Array jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to ask on how to write Multidimensional Array in jQuery ?

its oky if its in basic syntax, im still new to jQuery.

Comment: Similar post: "Array functions in jQuery" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477700/

Answer (score 2):

Its Javascript, not JQuery that handles the arrays, so what you really want is a tutorial on multidimensional arrays in Javascript.

[Here is a good one.](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript-two-dimensional-arrays.html)

Basically you define one array, then reference it inside another array.  For example:

```
var columns = new Array(3);
var rows = new Array(4);
rows[0] = columns;
```

This can then be accessed as follows:

```
rows[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

there are no multidimensional arrays in javascript, but you can have an array whose elements are arrays

```
  square = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]
  ]
```

arrays don't have to be of the same length

```
  triangle = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5],
      [6]
  ]
```

you can mix array and non-array elements

```
   wookie = [
        head,
    [hand, hand],
       belly,
     [foot, foot]
  ]
```