# Javascript - How to create an object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know if it is possible to declare an array in Javascript of the type "com.peregrine.servicecenter.PWS.Common.MessageType". In java it is easy but in javascript I have not idea. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this thread; it basically asks the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration

Comment: Is your question really "How do I declare something in *JavaScript* that is an instance of a particular *Java* class?" You do understand that Java and JavaScript are separate languages?

Comment: I've never worked with namespaces but I'm going to read about it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know they are separate but the question is about if you can "simulate" a java class array in Javascript. Thanks

Comment: @nnnnnn Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet. :-) (I know you know the difference user, but I couldn't help it)

Comment: @cwallenpoole - yes, I know the difference too. But the way the question was phrased there was no mention of simulating Java's package concept using JavaScript, or namespacing or whatever, it asked about declaring a variable of a specific type, "com.peregrine.servicecenter.etc...", which actually is a library available for Java.

Comment: you should update your question to say what you really mean. Even from your last comment it is not clear if you want to be able to simulate the specific Java class you mentioned, or do the namespace thing, "a.b.c.d.etc", or create a JavaScript array that is restricted to holding objects of a certain type, or...

Answer (score 2):

sure it's possible:

```
var myArray = [];
```

remember that javascript is not a statically typed language, so you don't need to declare an array of a specific type.... just an array. Now, given the type you're referring to, I don't think that's exactly what you're asking though...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The Array in JS doesn't care *what* you've put in it, or even that the array indexes are numeric. Java, on the other hand, requires strict typing of both. I'd even go so far as to say that even `Object[]` is a completely different paradigm from `[]`.

Comment: Bad news to me. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an array to *exclusively* consist of a particular type. However, you can declare an array (`var myArray = [];`) and you can add objects of your intended type to it (`myArray.push(myMessageType);`).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the array in such a way.

```
 var arr = [];
```

it can contain object or array of object by calling

```
 arr.push(x)
```

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

[Array functions in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477700/array-functions-in-jquery)

Comment: I tried that before but it still is a non type array. Thank you anyway.