# Format javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have following variables:

```
a = {y: 3, color: colors[0]}; 
b = {y: 5, color: colors[0]}; 
c = {y: 5, color: colors[0]}; 
d = {y: 3, color: colors[0]};
```

And I want something like this:

```
r = {y: 3, color: colors[0]}, 
    {y: 5, color: colors[0]}, 
    {y: 5, color: colors[0]}, 
    {y: 3, color: colors[0]};
```

How I can do this with these four variables? I tried something like:

```
r = a+b+c+d;
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that the specified output is syntactically valid. Do you want an array of objects?

Comment: What is sth? Use real words.

Comment: What do you want to sum up? The whole array or the values of object literals?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to create an object array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419502/javascript-how-to-create-an-object-array)

Answer (score 8):

If you want an array of objects, then first you construct an array (`[...]`) then objects inside the array (`{...}`).  Thus you end up with:

```
var r = [
    {y: 3, color: colors[0]}, 
    {y: 5, color: colors[0]},
    {y: 5, color: colors[0]},
    {y: 3, color: colors[0]}
];
```

Or, with your existing variables `var r = [a, b, c, d];`

Comment: Thanks for the Formatting, @Jason. +1