# Passing an array of functions as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
function test(e, f) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        $('#clickme').append("<button id='op" + i + "'>" + e[i] + "</button>")
        $('#op' + i).click(function () {
            f[i]();
        })
    }
}


$(function postPunk() {
    var func1 = function () {
        alert('1');
    }
    var func2 = function () {
        alert('2');
    }
    var func3 = function () {
        alert('3');
    }
    test(['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'], [func1, func2, func3]);
})
```

The click events aren't calling the functions. If I place an alert test in the click event, it fires fine.

Any ideas why this isn't working? It seems to be a problem with passing the array of functions as a parameter. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: didn't know `;` was optional in javascript. You are missing them at line 6, and the last line.

Comment: Are you looking at it in a console? There's an error: `TypeError: [3] is not a function "f"+[i]();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477700/array-functions-in-jquery

Check the above question. This may help you.

Comment: There's more "missing" `;` than that (each of the function expressions). They are "optional", but it is best **not** to leave them off.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) -- every day...

Comment: @WouterH **Explicit semicolons are optional in most places in JavaScript** (for code that is already written cleanly with one-statement per line). This will not cause any problems with the above code. Look up "ASI" (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) for the rules. I write *almost no* semicolons in JavaScript; know the rules and be consistent.

Comment: @pst - Don't put words in my mouth. My opinion does not constitute "your code has errors".

Comment: @JaredFarrish I did not mean to imply you thought it was wrong (as in in syntactically invalid). Too many people just follow along blindly without justification for when to use (or not use) semi-colons in JavaScript. The "+2" on that first comment especially irritated me ..

Comment: @pst - That's exactly why I think it's a "best practice" for those to get in the habit of doing *until* they know the rules better. Syntactically, it's my opinion it's better to learn [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FStrict_mode) first, then decide on comfort level with different options. I agree, it is simplistic to blindly follow rules. But it's not wrong to defer to ending statements when you're learning. (Plus, it borks Tidy Up in jsFiddle...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with every other question of this type, `i` keeps on changing.

Instead, try this:

```
for( var i=0; i<e.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // your code that depends on i not changing
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish Nope, because `f` doesn't change like `i` does.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the classic JavaScript issue, where they all be the last value (or `undefined` since `f[3]` doesn't exist), since that's the value of `i` after the loop.

Try to pass the function reference directly to the `click` handler.

```
function test(e, f) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        $('#clickme').append("<button id='op" + i + "'>" + e[i] + "</button>")
        $('#op' + i).click(f[i])
    }
}
```

Or, another solution is to make a function that returns a function.  This will allow it to "close" around `i`.

```
function test(e, f) {
    var makeFunc = function(i) {
        return function() {
            f[i]();
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        $('#clickme').append("<button id='op" + i + "'>" + e[i] + "</button>")
        $('#op' + i).click(makeFunc(i))
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For passing the function directly to `.click`. If `i` is not needed, this is the only sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the callback function uses the value of `i` after the loop has ended, so it points to an index outside the array. You need a closure in the loop so that each iteration gets its own instance of the variable:

```
function test(e, f) {
  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    $('#clickme').append("<button id='op" + i + "'>" + e[i] + "</button>");
    (function(i){
      $('#op' + i).click(function () {
        f[i]();
      });
    })(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/fH2Dk/3/

```
function test(e, f){    
     for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
         (function(i) {
            $('#clickme').append("<button id='op" + i + "'>" + e[i] + "</button>");
            $('#op' + i).click(function(){
                f[i]();
            });
        })(i);    
    }
}
```